# Adding multiple values or names

Tags: html

How can I add multiple values to have multiple names in this code:

```
<input id="nick" class="form-control" placeholder="Nick" readonly="readonly" value="Bob,Bill,Brian" maxlength="15" />
```

So, a random name is selected, either Bob, or Bill, or Brian. How can i get this to work?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Whenever a user clicks the button, it will choose one of the values and use it.
The code should only work in the value area.

Comment: so you want it to randomly pick values? or do you want the user to be able to chose?

Comment: It's random, not picking.

Comment: i would use PHP after you submit the form to do the randomization.

Comment: I don't know PHP. Any other ways? CSS?